# Android app signing into Firebase using email and password error

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use a firebase email/password login inside my app.whenever I click on the sign-in button, the app would crash with a very unclear reason on the log. The log is as follows :

### Error Log

> 2019-08-05 15:41:25.067 8157-8157/com.jesda.spiknix E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.jesda.spiknix, PID: 8157
>   kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>       at com.jesda.spiknix.Activities.SignUpActivity$clicks$1.onClick(SignUpActivity.kt:117)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
>       at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
>       at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

I've tried initializing each layout element (shouldn't be required in Kotlin version 1.3.31) but doesn't solve the problem. I've tried cleaning, rebuilding and restarting an Android Studio (even PC).

### Here is the SignUpActivity.kt where I tried implementing the sign-in

```java
  class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    lateinit var gso: GoogleSignInOptions
    lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager
    lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    lateinit var login_BTN: Button

    var RC_SIGN_IN = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_up_layout)
        // FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this)
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        try {
            val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                "com.jesda.spiknix",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
            )
            for (signature in info.signatures) {
                val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                md.update(signature.toByteArray())
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT))
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        }

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(applicationContext)
        //AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this@SignUpActivity)

        gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        login_BTN = findViewById(R.id.loginBTN)

        clicks()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val currentUser = mAuth?.currentUser
        if (currentUser != null) {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        finish()
    }



    fun clicks() {
        login_BTN.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            mAuth!!.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailET.text.toString(), pwET.text.toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("TAG", "signInWithEmail:success")
                        val user = mAuth!!.currentUser
                        updateUI()
                    } else {
                        // If sign-in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("TAG", "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@SignUpActivity, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                        //    updateUI(null)
                    }
                    // ...
                }
        }
        RegisterBTN.setOnClickListener {
            mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailET.text.toString(), pwET.text.toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("TAG", "createUserWithEmail:success")
                        val user = mAuth!!.currentUser
                        updateUI()
                    } else {
                        // If sign-in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("TAG", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@SignUpActivity, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                        // updateUI(null)
                    }

                }

        }
        gplusBTN.setOnClickListener {

            val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)


        }

    }

    fun updateUI() {
        var user_id = mAuth?.currentUser?.uid
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(user_id)
        startActivity(Intent(this@SignUpActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            println("Error code 1 $task")
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                //  val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
                println("Error code 2 $result")
                if (result.isSuccess) {
                    val account = result.signInAccount
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Signed in Using Google $account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Sign in Using Google Failed $task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                //  val task2 = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                //  handleSignInResult(result)
                //  firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account!!)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w("TAG", "Google sign in failed", e)
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

The error says null pointer exception yet the layouts are all present and the error points inside the "onClickListener " of the button which I click(for login button, an error would point to signInWithEmailAndPassword line).

### XML file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="jesda.com.spiknik.Activities.SignUpActivity">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="email"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/pwET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Password"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/loginBTN"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Log In"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/RegisterBTN"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Register"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="or"/>

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/gplusBTN"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>


       <!-- <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/FBlogin_button"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nameET_reg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Name"/>

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailET_reg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="email"/>

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pwET_reg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"/>

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pwET_re2g"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/RegisterBTN_reg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Register"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your xml file here?

Comment: And post your logcat too

Comment: @HardikChauhan added xml file

Comment: @MbuodileObiosio logcat already included under  Error Log